# We only have SQL Server Standard edition so no access to snapshot functionality. Options?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, snapshot

We only have SQL Servre Standard edition so I can't use the Snapshot functionality. Before spending the time just want to know if the following is possible (or if there is a better way) please:

At the end of every month I need to take a snapshot of the month and store it in table b. The following month take another snapshot and *append* that snapshots data to table b. And so on....

Is it possible to create a stored procedure to run at the end of every month that stores the snapshot data into a temp table A. Then using another stored procedure, take data from temp table A and *append* to table B?  The second procedure can have a drop table A.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes. Using `INSERT INTO / SELECT` you can do this easily. You don't need a temp table in the middle though you can insert it straight in

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

If I understand you, more or less, this is what you want:

- Lock the table
- Select everything into a staging table
- Move everything from that staging table into your destination

You can lock the entire table (this will prevent changes, but can lead to deadlocks).

```
INSERT INTO stagingTable (
  ... -- field list
)
SELECT
  ... -- field list
FROM
  myTable WITH (TABLOCK)
;
```

`TABLOCK` will place a shared lock on the table which will be released when the statement is executed (`READ COMMITTED` isolation level) or after the transaction is committed/rolled back (`SERIALIZABLE`).

If you want to keep the lock during the whole transaction, you can add the `HOLDLOCK` hint too, which switches the isolation level to serializable for the object, thus the lock will be released after COMMIT. Don't forget to start a transaction and commit/roll it back.

You can also use `TABLOCKX`, which is an exclusive lock preventing all processes to acquire a lock on the table or on anything on lower levels (pages, rows, etc) in the table. This will prevent concurrent reads too!

You can let the SQL Server to decide which lock it wants to use (a.k.a. omit the hint), in this case SQL Server may choose to use more granular locks (such as page or row locks) instead of locking the whole table.

Comment: All this locking is uneccessary. A staging table is also unecessary. What are you protecting against here?

Comment: I agree, the staging table is not necessary if you don't want to do further transformations. The lock hint could be omitted if the OP does not want to keep the lock during the whole transaction or place an exclusive lock on the table. Use case: copy the records, then do updates on the source table and prevent other processes to do anything between the select and the update.

Comment: So the purpose of the lock is to isolate a bunch of records so that they can be marked back into the table. Personally I prefer an additional batch field where the pattern is: 1. Update the batch field in the source table with a given status; 2. select only the records that have that status; 3. process the records; 4. Update the source table and move on to the next status

Comment: For simple copy-and-update I prefer to do an UPDATE..OUTPUT INTO. since we don't know the actual use-case, this may or may not be a good solution for the OP. The point is, that yes she/he can do it, all other factors are up to the OP.